# #endregion directive expected but the } is matching

Tags: c#

The following code gives an error #endregion directive expected at the end of the file. I have checked physically, but all the } are matching.

```
namespace Labour
{
    public partial class frm_GP_ProjectLPO : Form
    {
        #region PublicVariables
        //    int inNarrationCount = 0;
        //    string strCashOrParty = string.Empty;
        //    string strPrefix = string.Empty;
        //    string strSuffix = string.Empty;
        //    string strVoucherNo = string.Empty;
        //    string strOrderNo = string.Empty;
        //    string strBarcode = string.Empty;
        //    string strStatus = string.Empty;
        //    //ArrayList lstArrOfRemove = new ArrayList();
        //    string tableName = "PurchaseOrderMaster";
        //    string strProductCode = string.Empty;
        //    public static bool isEdit = false;
        decimal decPurchaseOrderMasterId = 0;
        decimal decPurchaseOrderDetailId = 0;
        decimal decPurchaseOrderMasterIdentity = 0;
        decimal decPurchaseSuffixPrefixId = 0;
        decimal decPurchaseOrderTypeId = 0;
        decimal decPurchaseVoucherId = 0;
        decimal decCurrentRate = 0;
        decimal decCurrentConversionRate = 0;
        //    bool isValueChange = true;
        bool isAutomatic = false;
        //    bool isValueChanged = false;
        //    bool isDoAfterGridFill = true;
        //    bool isAmountcalc = true;
        //    bool isCheck = false;
        //    frmLedgerPopup frmLedgerPopupObj;
        //    frmProductSearchPopup frmProductSearchPopupObj;
        //    DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl TextBoxControl;
        //    frmPurchaseOrderRegister frmPurchaseOrderRegisterObj;
        //    frmPurchaseOrderReport frmPurchaseOrderReportObj;
        //    frmVoucherSearch objVoucherSearch = null;
        //    frmDayBook frmDayBookObj = null;
        //    frmVoucherWiseProductSearch objfrmVoucherproduct = null;
        //    TransactionsGeneralFill TransactionGeneralFillObj = new TransactionsGeneralFill();
        //    AutoCompleteStringCollection ProductNames = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        //    AutoCompleteStringCollection ProductCodes = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        //    DataTable dtblunitconversionViewAll = new DataTable();
        //    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        //    #endregion
        //    #region Functions




        string fileName = "", fileSaveDir = @"C:\Docs";
        ProjectSP OProjectSP = new ProjectSP();
        CommonFunctions OCommonFunctions = new CommonFunctions();
        bool ISLoadComplete = false, ErrorExist = false, ISEdit = false;
        decimal ProjectLPOID = 0;
        public frm_GP_ProjectLPO()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public frm_GP_ProjectLPO(decimal projectLPOID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ProjectLPOID = projectLPOID;
        }


        private void frm_GP_ProjectLPO_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LaodCombos();
            cmbLpoType.SelectedItem = "Customer";
            cmbSupplier.Visible = false;
            lblSupplier.Visible = false;
            if (ProjectLPOID > 0)
            {
                LoadSelectedQoutation();
                LoadSeletcedQuotationDetail();
            }
        }
        private void LoadSeletcedQuotationDetail()
        {
            dgvEmployeeDetail.DataSource = OCommonFunctions.SelectData("sp_GP_tbl_GP_ProjectLPODetailSelectForGrid", "@projetlpomasterid", ProjectLPOID.ToString());
        }

        private void LaodCombos()
        {
            OCommonFunctions.FillCombo("ledgerName", "ledgerId", "tbl_AccountLedger where accountGroupId=26", cmbClient);
            OCommonFunctions.FillCombo("name", "projectid", "tbl_GP_ProjectMaster where clientid = " + cmbClient.SelectedValue, cmbProject);  //LoadProject
            OCommonFunctions.FillCombo("name", "categoryid", "tbl_GP_Category ", category);
            OCommonFunctions.FillCombo("ledgerName", "ledgerId", "tbl_AccountLedger where accountGroupId=22", cmbSupplier);
            LoadSites();
            //  OCommonFunctions.FillCombo("name", "siteid", "tbl_GP_SiteMaster s inner join tbl_GP_ProjectLPOMaster l on S.siteid = l.siteid and l.projectid = " + cmbProject.SelectedValue, cmbSite);  //Site

        }
        public void LoadSites()
        {
            DataTable dt = OCommonFunctions.SelectData("[sp_GP_LoadSiteByProject]", "@ProjectID", Convert.ToString(cmbProject.SelectedValue));
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                cmbSite.DataSource = dt;
                cmbSite.DisplayMember = "name";
                cmbSite.ValueMember = "siteid";
            }
        }
        private void LoadSelectedQoutation()
        {

            if (ProjectLPOID > 0)
            {
                ProjectLPOMasterInfo oProjectLPOMasterInfo = OProjectSP.ProjectLPOMasterView(ProjectLPOID);
                ProjectLPOID = oProjectLPOMasterInfo.projetlpomasterid;

                try { cmbProject.SelectedValue = oProjectLPOMasterInfo.projectid; }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                try { dtpDate.Value = oProjectLPOMasterInfo.date; }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                try { dtpFromDate.Value = oProjectLPOMasterInfo.fromdate; }
                catch (Exception es) { }
                try { dtpTODate.Value = oProjectLPOMasterInfo.todate; }
                catch (Exception ed) { }
                try { cmbSite.SelectedValue = oProjectLPOMasterInfo.siteid; }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                try { txtLPONumber.Text = oProjectLPOMasterInfo.lponumber; }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                try { cmbSupplier.SelectedValue = oProjectLPOMasterInfo.supplierid; }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                try
                {
                    if (oProjectLPOMasterInfo.Lpotype == 1)
                    {
                        cmbLpoType.SelectedItem = "Customer";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmbLpoType.SelectedItem = "Supplier";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
        }



        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SaveFunction();

                if (CheckUserPrivilege.PrivilegeCheck(PublicVariables._decCurrentUserId, this.Name, btnSave.Text))
                {

                    if (!ValidateData())
                    {
                        if (!DataExist())
                        {
                            if (Messages.SaveMessage())
                            {
                                if (SaveProjectLPO() > 0)
                                {
                                    Clear();
                                    // LoadFullEmployee();
                                    RefreshList();
                                    Messages.SavedMessage();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("LPO already exist");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Messages.NoPrivillageMessage();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cus20:" + ex.Message, "EasyERP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        private void Clear()
        {
            //txtName.Text = "";
            //txtPhone.Text = "";
        }
        private void RefreshList()
        {
            frm_GP_ProjectLPOList frm = Application.OpenForms["frm_GP_ProjectLPOList"] as frm_GP_ProjectLPOList;
            frm.LaodFullProjectLPO();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Print function
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="decMasterId"></param>
        public void Print(decimal decMasterId)
        {
            try
            {
                PurchaseOrderMasterSP spPurchaseOrderMaster = new PurchaseOrderMasterSP();
                DataSet dsPurchaseOrder = spPurchaseOrderMaster.PurchaseOrderPrinting(decMasterId);
                frmReport frmReport = new frmReport();
                frmReport.MdiParent = formMDI.MDIObj;
                frmReport.PurchaseOrderPrinting(dsPurchaseOrder);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PO14:" + ex.Message, "EasyERP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        ///  Print function for dotmatrix printer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="decMasterId"></param>
        public void PrintForDotMatrix(decimal decMasterId)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dtblOtherDetails = new DataTable();
                CompanySP spComapany = new CompanySP();
                dtblOtherDetails = spComapany.CompanyViewForDotMatrix();
                DataTable dtblGridDetails = new DataTable();
                dtblGridDetails.Columns.Add("SlNo");
                dtblGridDetails.Columns.Add("BarCode");
                dtblGridDetails.Columns.Add("ProductCode");
                dtblGridDetails.Columns.Add("ProductName");
                dtblGridDetails.Columns.Add("Qty");
                dtblGridDetails.Columns.Add("Unit");
                dtblGridDetails.Columns.Add("Rate");
                dtblGridDetails.Columns.Add("Amount");
                int inRowCount = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow dRow in dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows)
                {
                    if (!dRow.IsNewRow)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dtblGridDetails.NewRow();
                        dr["SlNo"] = ++inRowCount;
                        if (dRow.Cells["dgvtxtBarcode"].Value != null)
                        {
                            dr["BarCode"] = Convert.ToString(dRow.Cells["dgvtxtBarcode"].Value);
                        }
                        if (dRow.Cells["dgvtxtProductCode"].Value != null)
                        {
                            dr["ProductCode"] = Convert.ToString(dRow.Cells["dgvtxtProductCode"].Value);
                        }
                        if (dRow.Cells["dgvtxtProductName"].Value != null)
                        {
                            dr["ProductName"] = Convert.ToString(dRow.Cells["dgvtxtProductName"].Value);
                        }
                        if (dRow.Cells["dgvtxtQty"].Value != null)
                        {
                            dr["Qty"] = Convert.ToString(dRow.Cells["dgvtxtQty"].Value);
                        }
                        if (dRow.Cells["dgvcmbUnit"].Value != null)
                        {
                            dr["Unit"] = Convert.ToString(dRow.Cells["dgvcmbUnit"].FormattedValue);
                        }
                        if (dRow.Cells["dgvtxtRate"].Value != null)
                        {
                            dr["Rate"] = Convert.ToString(dRow.Cells["dgvtxtRate"].Value);
                        }
                        if (dRow.Cells["dgvtxtAmount"].Value != null)
                        {
                            dr["Amount"] = Convert.ToString(dRow.Cells["dgvtxtAmount"].Value);
                        }
                        dtblGridDetails.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                }
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("voucherNo");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("date");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("ledgerName");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("Narration");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("Currency");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("TotalAmount");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("DueDays");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("DueDate");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("CustomerAddress");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("CustomerTIN");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("CustomerCST");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("AmountInWords");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("Declaration");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("Heading1");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("Heading2");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("Heading3");
                dtblOtherDetails.Columns.Add("Heading4");
                DataRow dRowOther = dtblOtherDetails.Rows[0];
                dRowOther["voucherNo"] = txtLPONumber.Text;
                dRowOther["date"] = dtpDate.Text;
                dRowOther["ledgerName"] = cmbSupplier.Text;
                dRowOther["Narration"] = "LPO for a period of one month";
                dRowOther["Currency"] = "AED";
                dRowOther["TotalAmount"] = "NA";
                dRowOther["DueDays"] = "NA";
                dRowOther["DueDate"] = "NA";
                dRowOther["address"] = (dtblOtherDetails.Rows[0]["address"].ToString().Replace("\n", ", ")).Replace("\r", "");
                AccountLedgerSP spAccountLedger = new AccountLedgerSP();
                AccountLedgerInfo infoAccountLedger = new AccountLedgerInfo();
                infoAccountLedger = spAccountLedger.AccountLedgerView(Convert.ToDecimal(cmbSupplier.SelectedValue));
                dRowOther["CustomerAddress"] = (infoAccountLedger.Address.ToString().Replace("\n", ", ")).Replace("\r", "");
                dRowOther["CustomerTIN"] = infoAccountLedger.Tin;
                dRowOther["CustomerCST"] = infoAccountLedger.Cst;
                //  dRowOther["AmountInWords"] = new NumToText().AmountWords(Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalAmount.Text), PublicVariables._decCurrencyId);
                VoucherTypeSP spVoucherType = new VoucherTypeSP();
                DataTable dtblDeclaration = spVoucherType.DeclarationAndHeadingGetByVoucherTypeId(decPurchaseOrderTypeId);
                dRowOther["Declaration"] = Convert.ToString(dtblDeclaration.Rows[0]["Declaration"]);
                dRowOther["Heading1"] = Convert.ToString(dtblDeclaration.Rows[0]["Heading1"]);
                dRowOther["Heading2"] = Convert.ToString(dtblDeclaration.Rows[0]["Heading2"]);
                dRowOther["Heading3"] = Convert.ToString(dtblDeclaration.Rows[0]["Heading3"]);
                dRowOther["Heading4"] = Convert.ToString(dtblDeclaration.Rows[0]["Heading4"]);
                int inFormId = spVoucherType.FormIdGetForPrinterSettings(Convert.ToInt32(dtblDeclaration.Rows[0]["masterId"].ToString()));
                PrintWorks.DotMatrixPrint.PrintDesign(inFormId, dtblOtherDetails, dtblGridDetails, dtblOtherDetails);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PO15:" + ex.Message, "EasyERP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }


        // save function from purchaseorder.cs

        public void SaveFunction()
        {
            try
            {
                PurchaseOrderMasterInfo infoPurchaseOrderMaster = new PurchaseOrderMasterInfo();
                PurchaseOrderDetailsSP spPurchaseOrderDetails = new PurchaseOrderDetailsSP();
                PurchaseOrderDetailsInfo infoPurchaseOrderDetails = new PurchaseOrderDetailsInfo();
                PurchaseOrderMasterSP spPurchaseOrderMaster = new PurchaseOrderMasterSP();
                ProductInfo infoProduct = new ProductInfo();
                ProductSP spProduct = new ProductSP();
                SettingsSP spSettings = new SettingsSP();

                infoPurchaseOrderMaster.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpDate.Text);
                infoPurchaseOrderMaster.DueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpFromDate.Text);
                infoPurchaseOrderMaster.LedgerId = Convert.ToDecimal(cmbSupplier.SelectedValue.ToString());
                //if (isAutomatic == true)
                //{
                //    infoPurchaseOrderMaster.SuffixPrefixId = decPurchaseSuffixPrefixId;
                //    infoPurchaseOrderMaster.VoucherNo = strVoucherNo;
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    infoPurchaseOrderMaster.SuffixPrefixId = 0;
                //    infoPurchaseOrderMaster.VoucherNo = spPurchaseOrderMaster.VoucherNoMax(decPurchaseOrderTypeId);
                //}
                //infoPurchaseOrderMaster.VoucherTypeId = decPurchaseOrderTypeId;
                // infoPurchaseOrderMaster.InvoiceNo = txtOrderNo.Text;
                infoPurchaseOrderMaster.UserId = PublicVariables._decCurrentUserId;
                infoPurchaseOrderMaster.EmployeeId = PublicVariables._decCurrentUserId;//by default current userid used as current employeeid
                infoPurchaseOrderMaster.FinancialYearId = PublicVariables._decCurrentFinancialYearId;
                infoPurchaseOrderMaster.Narration = "LPO from Time Sheet"; //txtNarration.Text.Trim();
                //infoPurchaseOrderMaster.TotalAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalAmount.Text);
                // infoPurchaseOrderMaster.exchangeRateId = Convert.ToDecimal(cmbCurrency.SelectedValue.ToString());
                infoPurchaseOrderMaster.Extra1 = string.Empty;
                infoPurchaseOrderMaster.Extra2 = string.Empty;
                //infoPurchaseOrderMaster.DeliveryPeriod = txtDelivery.Text;
                //infoPurchaseOrderMaster.QuotationRef = txtQuotation.Text;
                // infoPurchaseOrderMaster.ProjectRef = txtProject.Text;
                //  infoPurchaseOrderMaster.PaymentTerms = txtTerms.Text;
                // infoPurchaseOrderMaster.Warrenty = txtWarrenty.Text;

                decPurchaseOrderMasterIdentity = Convert.ToDecimal(spPurchaseOrderMaster.PurchaseOrderMasterAdd(infoPurchaseOrderMaster));
                int inRowcount = dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows.Count;
                for (int inI = 0; inI < inRowcount - 1; inI++)
                {
                    infoPurchaseOrderDetails.PurchaseOrderMasterId = decPurchaseOrderMasterIdentity;
                    if (dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvtxtProductCode"].Value != null && dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvtxtProductCode"].Value.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        infoProduct = spProduct.ProductViewByCode(dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvtxtProductCode"].Value.ToString());
                        infoPurchaseOrderDetails.ProductId = infoProduct.ProductId;
                    }
                    if (dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvtxtQty"].Value != null && dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvtxtQty"].Value.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        infoPurchaseOrderDetails.Qty = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvtxtQty"].Value.ToString());
                    }
                    if (dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvcmbUnit"].Value != null && dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvcmbUnit"].Value.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        infoPurchaseOrderDetails.UnitId = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvcmbUnit"].Value);
                        infoPurchaseOrderDetails.UnitConversionId = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvtxtUnitConversionId"].Value.ToString());
                    }
                    infoPurchaseOrderDetails.Rate = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvtxtRate"].Value.ToString());
                    infoPurchaseOrderDetails.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvtxtAmount"].Value.ToString());
                    infoPurchaseOrderDetails.SlNo = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[inI].Cells["dgvtxtSlNo"].Value.ToString());
                    infoPurchaseOrderDetails.Extra1 = string.Empty;
                    infoPurchaseOrderDetails.Extra2 = string.Empty;
                    spPurchaseOrderDetails.PurchaseOrderDetailsAdd(infoPurchaseOrderDetails);
                }
                Messages.SavedMessage();

                if (spSettings.SettingsStatusCheck("Printer") == "Dot Matrix")
                {
                    PrintForDotMatrix(decPurchaseOrderMasterIdentity);
                }
                else
                {
                    Print(decPurchaseOrderMasterIdentity);
                }

                Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PO35:" + ex.Message, "EasyERP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        // Save function from purchaseorser.cs ends
        private decimal SaveProjectLPO()
        {
            decimal projectLPOID = 0;
            ProjectLPOMasterInfo oProjectLPOMasterInfo = new ProjectLPOMasterInfo();
            oProjectLPOMasterInfo.projetlpomasterid = ProjectLPOID;
            try { oProjectLPOMasterInfo.projectid = Convert.ToDecimal(cmbProject.SelectedValue); }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            oProjectLPOMasterInfo.date = dtpDate.Value;
            oProjectLPOMasterInfo.fromdate = dtpFromDate.Value;
            oProjectLPOMasterInfo.todate = dtpTODate.Value;
            oProjectLPOMasterInfo.lponumber = txtLPONumber.Text;
            try { oProjectLPOMasterInfo.siteid = Convert.ToDecimal(cmbSite.SelectedValue); }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            try { oProjectLPOMasterInfo.supplierid = cmbLpoType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Customer" ? 0 : Convert.ToDecimal(cmbSupplier.SelectedValue); }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            try { oProjectLPOMasterInfo.filename = fileName; }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
            try
            {
                if (cmbLpoType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Customer")
                {
                    oProjectLPOMasterInfo.Lpotype = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    oProjectLPOMasterInfo.Lpotype = 2;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }

            bool isEdit = false;
            if (oProjectLPOMasterInfo.projetlpomasterid > 0)
            {
                isEdit = true;
            }

            projectLPOID = OProjectSP.ProjectLPOMasterAddOREdit(oProjectLPOMasterInfo, isEdit);
            if (projectLPOID > 0)
            {
                bool isSaved = SaveLPODetail(projectLPOID);
            }

            return projectLPOID;
        }

        private bool SaveLPODetail(decimal projectLPOID)
        {

            decimal projectLPODetailID = 0;
            bool isEdit = false;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvEmployeeDetail.Rows)
            {
                ProjectLPODetailInfo oProjectLPODetailInfo = new ProjectLPODetailInfo();
                oProjectLPODetailInfo.projetlpomasterid = projectLPOID;
                if (dr.Index != dgvEmployeeDetail.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    try { oProjectLPODetailInfo.projectlpodetailid = Convert.ToDecimal(dr.Cells["projectDetailID"].Value); }
                    catch (Exception ex) { }
                    oProjectLPODetailInfo.categoryid = Convert.ToDecimal(dr.Cells["category"].Value);
                    try { oProjectLPODetailInfo.nooflabour = Convert.ToInt32(dr.Cells["NumberOFEmployee"].Value); }
                    catch (Exception ex) { }
                    try { oProjectLPODetailInfo.rate = Convert.ToDecimal(dr.Cells["reatePerHour"].Value); }
                    catch (Exception ex) { }


                    if (oProjectLPODetailInfo.projectlpodetailid > 0)
                    {
                        isEdit = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isEdit = false;
                    }
                    projectLPODetailID = OProjectSP.ProjectLPODetailAddOREdit(oProjectLPODetailInfo, isEdit);
                    if (projectLPODetailID <= 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (projectLPODetailID > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

        private bool DataExist()
        {
            return false;
        }

        private bool ValidateData()
        {
            //if (txtName.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
            //{
            //    Messages.InformationMessage("Enter employee name ");
            //    txtName.Focus();
            //    return true;
            //}
            return false;
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
            openFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
            openFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
            string fileNewPath = "";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (string fileNamepath in openFileDialog.FileNames)
                {
                    txtFilename.Text = fileNamepath;

                }
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilename.Text))
            {
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(txtFilename.Text.Trim());
                fileName = txtLPONumber.Text + fileName;
                fileNewPath = Path.Combine(fileSaveDir, fileName);
                File.Copy(txtFilename.Text.Trim(), fileNewPath);
            }
            }
            private bool SaveFile()
            {
            //if (txtName.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
            //{
            //    Messages.InformationMessage("Enter employee name ");
            //    txtName.Focus();
            //    return true;
            //}
            return false;
        }




        private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet dsLPODetails = OProjectSP.ProjectLPODetails(ProjectLPOID);
                frmReport frmReport = new frmReport();
                frmReport.MdiParent = formMDI.MDIObj;
                frmReport.ProjectLPOPrint(dsLPODetails);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PO14:" + ex.Message, "EasyERP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        private void cmbProject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmbSite.DataSource = null;
            if (cmbProject.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                if (cmbProject.SelectedValue.ToString() != "System.Data.DataRowView")
                {
                    // cmbSite.DataSource = null;
                    LoadSites();
                }
            }
        }

        private void cmbSite_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void cmbClient_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbClient.SelectedValue.ToString() != "System.Data.DataRowView")
            {
                cmbProject.DataSource = null;
                OCommonFunctions.FillCombo("name", "projectid", "tbl_GP_ProjectMaster where clientid = " + cmbClient.SelectedValue, cmbProject);
            }
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void cmbLpoType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbLpoType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Supplier")
            {
                cmbSupplier.Visible = true;
                lblSupplier.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cmbSupplier.Visible = false;
                lblSupplier.Visible = false;

            }
        }


    }

}
```

I tried restarting the IDE, Reopening the solution etc but it did not work out.

Comment: #endregion matches with #region not with }

Answer (score 7):

Just as the message says - you are lacking an

```
#endregion
```

in your code.

Right in the beginning, there's an opening

```
#region
```

that is never closed.

Answer (score 3):

For each #region tag you have you need a closing #endregion tag. You are using

```
#region PublicVariables
```

But not closing it with #endregion (it's being closed but it's commented out)

More information here [MSDN Region C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

On line 3, a `#region` starts, but on line 43 the matching `#endregion` is commented out.

Answer (score 2):

Your class starts with a `#region`:

```
public partial class frm_GP_ProjectLPO : Form
{
    #region PublicVariables
    .
    .
    .
```

So you need a matching `#endregion' below:

```
    .
    .
    .
    #endregion
    .
    .
    .
}
```

You can add the region name if you want.