# Why am I getting #endregoin diretive expected error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting `#endregoin diretive expected` in this class:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

public class MobileInput : MonoBehaviour {

    private const float DEADZONE = 100.0f;

    public static MobileInput Instance { set; get; }

    private bool tap, swipeLeft, swipeLeft, swipeRight, swipeUp, swipeUp, swipeDown;
    private Vector2 swipeDelta, startTouch;

    public bool Tap { get { return tap; } }
    public Vector2 SwipeDelta { get { return swipeDelta; } }
    public Vector2 SwipeLeft { get { return swipeLeft; } }
    public Vector2 SwipeRight { get { return swipeRight; } }
    public Vector2 SwipeUp { get { return swipeUp; } }
    public Vector2 SwipeDown { get { return swipeDown; } }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //reseting all the bool
        tap = swipeLeft = swipeRight = swipeDown = swipeUp = false;

        //lets check input

        #region Standalone Inputs
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            tap = true;
            startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseBottonUp(0))
        {
            startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        }

        #region Mobile Inputs
        if (Input.touches.Length != 0)
        {
            if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                tap = true;
                startTouch = Input.mousePosition;
            }
            else if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)
            {
                startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
            }

        }
        #endregion

        //Calculate 
        swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        if (startTouch != Vector2.zero)
        {
            //let's check
            if (Input.touches.Length != 0)
            {
                swipeDelta = Input.touches[0].position - startTouch;
            }
            //lets check standalone 
            else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                swipeDelta = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition - startTouch;
            }
        }

        //Check dead zone
        if (swipeDelta.magnitude > DEADZONE)
        {

            // this is a confirmed swip
            float x = swipeDelta.x;
            float y = swipeDelta.y;

            if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
            {
                //left
                if (x < 0)
                    swipeLeft = true;
                else
                    swipeRight = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //up or down
                if (y < 0)
                    swipeDown = true;
                else
                    swipeUp = true;

            }

            startTouch = swipeDelta = Vector2.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @drescherjm C# I am thinking. Could be BSPL, though.

Comment: @user4581301 It's c# under Unity3d

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#endregion directive expected but the } is matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444306/endregion-directive-expected-but-the-is-matching)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto good. I hate BSPL.

Comment: You're missing an `#endregion` directive, just as it says.  Look for all of your `#region` statements and make sure there is a corresponding `#endregion` for each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Your `#region Standalone Inputs` is missing an `#endregion` further down in your code.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm curious now, what's the rational? I've been using them to set up a block of code that can be collapsed independently of any containing block they are in (and even then, sparingly).

Comment: @Draco18s I learned that some years ago. The rational is that: if your code is so long it needs to be hidden in regions, you need to refactor.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That kinda makes sense. The only place I'm using it right now is around long lists of static properties (e.g. I have a class that tracks statistics, so I have a field for each statistic being tracked, `StatTracker.PointsScored = new Stat(...)` etc).